# Time difference between two cities/ countries when we have current time and timezone for respective place

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I need to know the time difference between two cities. I have current time of both of the cities and their time zones too. I tried to get the difference using **getOffset**, however it's showing time difference between GMT(UTC) and the respective place.

Below is the code I am using in php to find out the difference:

```
$dateTimeZone1 = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta");
$dateTimeZone2 = new DateTimeZone("America/New_York");
$dateTime1 = new DateTime("now", $dateTimeZone1);
$dateTime2 = new DateTime("now", $dateTimeZone2);
$timeOffset = $dateTimeZone1->getOffset($dateTime2);
echo ($timeOffset/3600);
```

The above code always gives a difference of time from UTC which I don't want... I want exact or near exact time difference between two cities.

N:B:- For an example 
ASIA/Calcutta - AMERICA/NEW_YORK =  - 11 hours (America is 11 hours behind India)

Comment: Couldn't you do a getOffset for both and then add them together?

Comment: Sounds good!!! lets give it a try and will let you know @scoota269

Comment: demo code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162697/get-time-zone-offset-between-two-timezones-for-a-given-duration

Answer (score 0):

Get the offset for both timezones and add them together.